# Page Source is not reflecting the changes after submitting a form through selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have created a script which will fill the form and submit it.
the website then displays the results.

once i open chrome using selenium, i get the driver.page_source and it gives the correct html output of the initial state.

If i use the driver.page_source after submitting the form,i am only getting the source of the initial state again, that is: no change is reflected even though there is a change in the html.

Question: How do i get the HTML output of the page with changes after submitting the form?

Thanks for the help in advance!
ps: i'm new so yeah..

EDIT: 
I found the answer, it was working fine all the while, but the web page hadn't fully loaded yet and hence i was still getting the old source code, so i just made the driver wait before extracting the new source. 
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you *submit the form* before you pull out the `page_source` to *check for the change*, it is worth to mention that though the *WebClient* may have achieved `'document.readyState'` equal to `"complete"` at a certain stage and *Selenium* gets back the control of program execution, that doesn't guarantees that all the associated *Javascript* and *Ajax Calls* on the new page have completed. Until and unless the *Javascript* and *Ajax Calls* associated with the *DOM Tree* gets completed the page is not completely rendered you may not be able to track the intended changes.

An ideal way to *check for changes* would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set as [**title_contains**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains) as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_element_changes_page").click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.title_contains(("full_or_partial_text_of_the_new_page_title")))
source = driver.page_source
```

**Note** : While **Page Title** resides within the `<head>` tag of the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) a better solution would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) for the visibility of an element which will be present in all situations within the `<body>` tag of the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_element_changes_page").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_element_present_in_all_situation")))
source = driver.page_source
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Selenium's current page to the scrapy Selector and use usual css and/or xpath selectors to get data from it:

```
sel_response = Selector(text=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
sel_response.css(<your_css_selector>).extract()
```